# Регулярное выражение на замену Camel Case

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Как составить регулярку, чтобы `preg_replace` производил замену

- `IsActive => is_active`
- `NewParamA => new_param_a`
- `SNTest => s_n_test`
- `ABC => a_b_c`
- `ABCd => a_b_cd`

Т. е. перед каждой заглавной буквой должно ставиться нижнее подчеркивание (кроме первой буквы).

Answer (score 3):

```
<?
$str = 'ThisStringIsCamelCaseExample';
echo $str . ' / ' . strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=.)[A-Z]/', '_$0', $str));
?>

out: ThisStringIsCamelCaseExample / this_string_is_camel_case_example
```